# Is it safe to use floor(a/b)?

Tags: floating-point

In many programming languages, there is a function called floor, which takes one floating-point argument (a double or a single), and returns the largest integer number that is not larger than the argument. Now I have a question : Is it safe to get the largest integer number that is not larger than a/b, by calling floor(a/b)? I think that floating-point computations may be inexact. So, for example, the exact value of a/b may be 2.999999998, but it may be computed to be 3.00000000, and then floor(a/b) gets 3, which is incorrect.

Comment: Are `a` and `b` integers, or general floats?

Comment: If `a` and `b` are integers within reasonable bounds, and we can assume IEEE 754 semantics, then yes, it's safe (roughly because if the result of the division is a not-too-large integer then `a/b` will be computed without error, while if it's not an integer and `a` and `b` aren't too large then the division result can't be too close to an integer). If that's the case you're interested in, please say so, so that someone can construct a proper answer.

Comment: I mean, a and b are general floating-point numbers, but they are exactly represented. If it is difficult to answer this, answering about integers is also okay.

Comment: Thanks for the update; in that case, looks like Simon Byrne already has your answer.

Comment: Define what exactly you mean by "safe"? "Doesn't cause an error"? "Returns the correct result"? Define "correct" in the context of an imprecise number system…

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if using IEEE754 binary64 format (i.e. a typical C `double` on most systems). An example is when `a = 0.9` (which, as 0.9 cannot be represented by the format, is actually 0.90000000000000002220446049250313080847263336181640625) and `b = 0.1` (actually 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625) then the true value of `a/b` is actually

8.999999999999999722444243843710880301531638075180891038116311176859261171872...

however this will get rounded to `9.0`, as it is closer to 9 than the previous floating point number

8.9999999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875

so `floor(a/b)` will also be `9.0`.

Comment: where did you get that `8.9999999999999997224442438437108803015316380751808910...` will be rounded to `9.0`?

Answer (score 0):

It is safe if `a` and `b` are integers (less than power(2, size of mantissa + 2)) or if `a` and `b` are "exactly" represented.

*START_UPDATE*

The question can be reformulated into: is it possible to have `a/b = n` with `a < n*b`?

The argument is rather complicated but the answer is no to this question:

If `a < n*b` then `a <= n*b - eps(n*b)/2`.

The worst case is when `eps(n*b)/2` is close but less than a power of 2. But even in this worst case, you have

```
   a < n*b - n*b*eps(1.0)/4
```

So

```
   a/b exactly evaluated < n - n*eps(1.0)/4
   a/b exactly evaluated < n - eps(n)/4
```

and the round to nearest even mode ensures that

```
   a/b in floating-point < n
```

*END_UPDATE*

Suppose now that the exact value of `a/b` is an integer `n` with a down-approximated `a` and an up-approximated `b`. Then `a/b` could be down-approximated with more than 1/2 unit in the last place and so be less than `n`. Hence the exact value of `a/b = n` whereas `floor(a/b) = n-1`.

The following C++ code returns 126 exceptions of `floor((i/1000)/0.001)` that are different from `i`. The first one is `0.043/0.001`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main() {
  double x, y;
  for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++  i) {
    x = i / 1000.0;
    y = 0.001;
    if (floor(x/y) != (double) i)
       std::cout << i << ' ' << floor(x/y) << '\n';
  }
  std::cout.flush();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, that is not what I mean. I mean: Is it safe when a and b are exactly represented?

Comment: Yes it is safe.

Comment: More explanations in the post; you are right, the initial post missed the more important point.